# "Indicated packet length too large" error when using remote interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, sftp

I am setting up a remote SSH interpreter in PyCharm, but when I try to select the interpreter's location on the remote machine, I get the following error:

```
Indicated packet length 1952805748 too large
```

How can I fix this?

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Answer (score 13):

I got this error because my `.bashrc` file printed to stdout. `.bashrc` is sourced when PyCharm connects to a remote interpreter's machine over SFTP. It has to be silent, otherwise it interferes with the SFTP protocol.

The solution is to exit `.bashrc` early when not running interactively by putting this line at the top:

```
# If not running interactively, return early
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return
```

Further reading:

- [Indicated packet length 1953461345 too large (JetBrains forum)](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007648499-Indicated-packet-length-1953461345-too-large)
- [SSHException: Indicated packet length 1097295214 too large (PyCharm issue tracker)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38929)

Comment: I'm not using bashrc. I am using zshrc in my new macbook m1 max. How does this affect your solution? Also are you talking about the bashrc file in my local machine or the machine in the server?

Comment: ok your talking about the one in the sever. For me I was printing a bunch of things in my bashrc so I assume when it logged into the server there were issues.

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit check, I found the final solution for this problem.

It is not a problem about `pycharm` or `intellij` actually.

The underlying working principle of `sync` files to the remote server is using `sftp` to upload files and download files from a remote server.

Maybe you have noticed that it works when using the `root` user to sync.

For different people, they use different `sftp` utils like `putty`, `Linux client`, `Windows cmd`, `Power shell`, `xshell`, and so on.

By using the command `sftp root@host` or `sftp user@host` (where the user is what you logged) in `xshell`.

`xshell` will ask you to type in a password with a dialog.

Both these commands will work.

But when you use `windows cmd` by the same commands, here messages will jump out.

```
Received message too long 1399157792
Ensure the remote shell produces no output for non-interactive sessions.
```

And you will see, `pycharm` just forward this information.

Here is a related question about the long message, [sftp gives an error: "Received message too long" and what is the reason?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61580/sftp-gives-an-error-received-message-too-long-and-what-is-the-reason)

So, we need to change the `sftp server` configuration to `non-interactive` mode.

By editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, need you to have `root permission` or ask the server administrator to do.

```sh
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

And restart the `sshd` service, by `systemctl restart sshd`

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issues. I was pip updating a bunch of software in the cluster each time I logged in. So if pycharm runs the bashrc in the cluster each time it pushes and for some reason it processes it's output then this is an issue. I removed all lines that print in my bashrc in the remote/cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful not to add `[[ $- == *i* ]] || return` to your `.bashrc` unless it's your local machine.

Similar to the one described here, scp complained about the output from .bashrc (it gives a greeting upon login). Funny that FreeBSD or OpenBSD SSH never complained about the same. But Ubuntu...

Well I remembered having similar problem with some versions of SSH in the past, so I did add `[[ $- == *i* ]] || return` to my `.bashrc`, as Killan Obermeier above suggests. I did it, and the next time was unable to login nor locally nor remotely. Upon receiving the right password the prompt would just reset back to login LOL. It's a mercy this wasn't some remote machine.